# Concatenate/paste strings of varying length according to index

Tags: r, string, concatenation, aggregate, paste

I would like to know how to concatenate string to form sequences of different and **varying lengths** & varying content according to one condition.

Here is a dataframe example (my DF is actually about 60000 rows).

1. `column index`: just an index
2. `to_concat`: the string item i want to concatenate
3. `max_seq`: one example of the condition for concatenation (to_concat should only concatenate if it is part of the same sequence - and I have indicated the position of the string in the sequence for now.
4. `concat_result`: The result I would like to have

   ```
   index to_concat  max_seq    concat_result
   1        Abc!      1         <abc!+def+_>
   2        def       2         <abc!+def+_>
   3        _         3         <abc!+def+_>
   4        x93       1         <x93+afza+5609+5609+Abc!+def>
   5        afza      2         <x93+afza+5609+5609+Abc!+def>
   6        5609      3         <x93+afza+5609+5609+Abc!+def>
   7        5609      4         <x93+afza+5609+5609+Abc!+def>
   8        Abc!      5         <x93+afza+5609+5609+Abc!+def>
   9        def       6         <x93+afza+5609+5609+Abc!+def>
   10        _         1         <_+x93+afza>
   11        x93       2         <_+x93+afza>
   12        afza      3         <_+x93+afza>
   ```

I know of `paste` & `aggregate`, `length`, probably usefull.. But do not see in which order to do that and especially how to formulate the paste.

I suppose I should also include an "second" index better done for `max_seq` (such as : all strings to be concatenated in the same sequence have the same number so here we would have a 3 sequences " 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 ".

But I do not know if that is the quickest/easiest solution and also I do not know how to paste varying length...

*Could you please help a fellow PhD? Thanks a lot in advance.*

---

Reproductible example: 
`dput(dat)`

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(V1 = c("index", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"), V2 = c("to_concat", "Abc!", 
"def", "_", "x93", "afza", "5609", "5609", "Abc!", "def", "_", 
"x93", "afza"), V3 = c("max_seq", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "1", "2", "3"), V4 = c("concat_result", "<abc!+def+_>", 
"<abc!+def+_>", "<abc!+def+_>", "<x93+afza+5609+5609+Abc!+def>", 
"<x93+afza+5609+5609+Abc!+def>", "<x93+afza+5609+5609+Abc!+def>", 
"<x93+afza+5609+5609+Abc!+def>", "<x93+afza+5609+5609+Abc!+def>", 
"<x93+afza+5609+5609+Abc!+def>", "<_+x93+afza>", "<_+x93+afza>", 
"<_+x93+afza>")), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-13L))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several options to get the desired result:

**1)** Using base R:

```
mydf$grp <- cumsum(mydf$max_seq < c(1,head(mydf$max_seq, -1))) + 1
mydf$concat_result <- ave(mydf$to_concat, mydf$grp, 
                          FUN = function(x) paste0('<',paste(x,collapse='+'),'>'))
```

which gives:

```
> mydf
   index to_concat max_seq grp                 concat_result
1      1      Abc!       1   1                  <Abc!+def+_>
2      2       def       2   1                  <Abc!+def+_>
3      3         _       3   1                  <Abc!+def+_>
4      4       x93       1   2 <x93+afza+5609+5609+Abc!+def>
5      5      afza       2   2 <x93+afza+5609+5609+Abc!+def>
6      6      5609       3   2 <x93+afza+5609+5609+Abc!+def>
7      7      5609       4   2 <x93+afza+5609+5609+Abc!+def>
8      8      Abc!       5   2 <x93+afza+5609+5609+Abc!+def>
9      9       def       6   2 <x93+afza+5609+5609+Abc!+def>
10    10         _       1   3                  <_+x93+afza>
11    11       x93       2   3                  <_+x93+afza>
12    12      afza       3   3                  <_+x93+afza>
```

**2)** Or using the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)[, grp := cumsum(max_seq < shift(max_seq, fill = 0))+1
            ][, concat_result := paste0('<',paste(to_concat,collapse='+'),'>'), grp][]
```

**3)** Or using the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %>%
  mutate(grp = cumsum(max_seq < lag(max_seq, n=1, default=0))+1) %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  mutate(concat_result = paste0('<',paste(to_concat,collapse='+'),'>'))
```

---

Used data:

```
mydf <- structure(list(index = 1:12, 
                       to_concat = c("Abc!", "def", "_", "x93", "afza", "5609", "5609", "Abc!", "def", "_", "x93", "afza"), 
                       max_seq = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L)), 
                  .Names = c("index", "to_concat", "max_seq"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: Thank you for the several options in your rapid answer @ProcrastinatusMaximus. I would personnally go with the Base R one as it the most readable for any R user.

Comment: @prosodis True. But when speed and memory efficiency are an issue, then the `data.table` alternative would be the best way to go.